# Practical reasons to use procs?

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby and understand the concepts of blocks, but procs are really puzzling me.

Can you illustrate some practical use-cases that would benefit from using procs, that a beginner could easily understand?

Comment: blocks can be passed to functions, but not stored in variables. Anytime you want to store a function in a: variable / value of hash key / element in an array etc. you can use `proc` to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical example is the command pattern, e.g., map strings to procs:

The command arrives and is dispatched to its associated proc via the map.

Answer (score 0):

I built a chess game as part of my own Ruby learning process. An example of when I used a proc in a non-proc oriented exercise 'in the wild' was in defining the movement for pieces that moved linearly and not in a predefined number of spaces.

The `Piece` class holds all the stuff used by multiple pieces:

```
Class Piece

  @available_moves = []

  def linear_movement (x = 1, moves = [], &direction) # <= proc in parameters
    move = yield (x) # <= call to proc
    if on_board?(move) && (capture?(move) || empty?(move)) && (moves[-1] == nil || !capture?(moves[-1]))
      moves << move
      linear_movement( x + 1, moves, &direction) # <= recursive call *
    else
      moves
    end
  end

  def move_ul
    Proc.new { |x| "#{ left(x).chr }#{ forward(x) }" }
  end

  def move_dl
    Proc.new { |x| "#{ left(x).chr }#{ backward(x) }" }
  end

  def move_ur
    Proc.new { |x| "#{ right(x).chr }#{ forward(x) }" }
  end

  def move_dr
    Proc.new { |x| "#{ right(x).chr }#{ backward(x) }" }
  end

end
```

The `Bishop` class has the bishop specific logic:

```
Class Bishop < Piece

  def populate_available_moves
    @available_moves = []
    directions = [move_ul, move_dl, move_ur, move_dr]
    directions.each {|x| @available_moves.concat(linear_movement(&x))} # <= practical application
  end

end
```

Other pieces with linear movement have similar methods. There are method calls in here that aren't fully illustrated, but the important thing is an example of a use of Procs in the wild.

Depending on your level of "beginnerness", the string interpolation should be pretty straight forward, and class inheritance is probably also covered by the time one would be looking into Procs. The recursion is probably the only thing that you might not have covered yet (a call to a method within itself), so maybe don't think too hard on that one until you've had a chance to study it. Recursion aside, I think it should mostly be reachable by a beginner.